Spyder's "runfile" doesn't leave last answer in variable "_"
From the Spyder console, I issue runfile to invoke a Python
script (say) TryGroupBy.py:
runfile("C:/cygwin64/home/User.Name/prj/TheProject/LearnPandas/20240515groupby/TryGroupBy.py",
        current_namespace=True)

The last two lines in the script performs a pandas group-by operation
and (i) assigns it to a variable n2_by_state and also (ii) invokes
the same the operation without assigning it to any variable:
n2_by_state = df.groupby("state").first_name.count()
df.groupby(["state", "gender"])["last_name"].count()

I figure that output of one of these should end up in the Python
underscore variable "_" for the last result.  Neither do.  If I
issue the last command at the Spyder console prompt, however, I
do get output and variable "_" gets the result.
I thought that maybe runfile is running in its own scope.  The fact that objects created by TryGroupBy.py end up in Spyder's Variable Explorer suggests otherwise, but I thought it worthwhile to test this anyway.  I supplied optional argument current_namespace=True to runfile, but the result is the same.
Perhaps "_" is only assigned results from commands entered directly at
the console prompt.  I tried help(runfile) to get more specifics on
whether the script passed to runfile gets parsed by Spyder, IPython, or
the Python interpreter.  The help is very brief, describing only the
arguments.  I haven't found the answer in an online search.  From a
limited search, my impression is that runfile is part of Spyder rather
than IPython.
I also did a web search to find whether "_" is native to core
Python or whether it is an add-on in IPython or Spyder.  It seems
to be associated with Python proper.  As a test, therefore, I added
print(_) to the end of TryGroupBy.py, but nothing got printed out.
Is runfile really part of Spyder?  Is variable "_" really part of
core Python?  What are the rules that determine when variable "_"
receives the results of the last operation or evaluation?
